# Is there any way to debug apps over Wi-Fi or bluetooth? [Please note that the device is not connected via USB]

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-wifi, usb-debugging

For some reason (I don't know what), my phone is not getting connected over USB for debugging purposes.

I have checked that the device drivers are properly installed and the USB debugging option inside phone settings is checked.

Due to this, I am facing difficulties in debugging apps on device. I always have to export the apk and install it in my phone and do a sort of black box testing.

Is there any way that I could debug apps over Wi-Fi or Bluetooth...?

NOTE : I am using an android phone with KitKat 4.4.2 installed.

Comment: Essentially, no.  A stock device won't support ADB-over-TCP unless you first use ADB-over-USB to tell it to.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Although, my device gets connected in MTP mode, that means connection with computer is established, I am just not able to debug. :(

Comment: If MTP works, the remaining issue is presumably a software one, and therefore fixable.

Comment: @ChrisStratton : Can you help me finding a fix for it..?

Comment: See also, http://android.stackexchange.com/q/6949/59983

Comment: Using Wifi ADB Ultimate you can also connect device without usage of USB cable for first time. You just insert device's IP address of device.

Comment: Hello. I read that some USB-cables don't have data transfer ability, just electric charging.

Comment: Android 11+ has a developer option Wireless Debugging. Then use adb pair ipaddr:port https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb#connect-to-a-device-over-wi-fi-android-11+

Answer (score 17):

IntelliJ and Android Studio plugin created to quickly connect your Android device over WiFi to install, run and debug your applications without a USB connected. Press one button and forget about your USB cable.

just install plugin Android WiFi ADB

**Download and install Android WiFi ADB directly from
Intellij / Android Studio: Preferences/Settings->Plugins->Browse Repositories**

[![Browse repositories ][2]][2]

[image: DEvices list]

Comment: I'm using Wifi ADB Ultimate in which you can also connect device with inserting it's IP address. I also tried ADB Wifi Connect, but it didn't work.

Comment: it requires 1 time usb insert over 24 hours.

Comment: means in 24 hours meantime you can connect to wifi adb after disconnecting through wifi adb.

Answer (score 6):

Connecting using wifi requires to use usb wire once(Without Rooting)
Here is the process for that 
[How can I connect to Android with ADB over TCP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604727/how-can-i-connect-to-android-with-adb-over-tcp)

If usb is not working you should checkout debugging over bluetooth (Without Rooting)

http://blog.wijono.org/2014/01/android-connecting-adb-to-physical.html

http://zcourts.com/2013/07/19/android-debugging-over-bluetooth-without-root/#sthash.hVCLtWSk.dpbs

Comment: The second to last link is dead unfortunately, but the last link works perfectly!